# Error when I run a clone PHP project using laravel from github

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, github

So I just try to run the project, I have migrate the database but, when I run it shows the following error message:

```
 SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dompet_db.transactions' doesn't exist.
```

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: check the migration table transactions

Comment: The error says that the table named `transactions` is not present in the database. Check your migrations to make sure that you have a migration for this table and then run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: Yes check if migration file exist in "database/migrations"

Comment: Ive done it, but error message still showed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the usual steps that we do while cloning a project.

1. clone the repo
2. **composer install**
3. **cp .env.example .env**  (copy .env.example and create .env file)
4. configure the database **DB_DATABASE**, **DB_USERNAME**, **DB_PASSWORD**
5. **php artisan key:generate**  (generates encryption key)
6. **php artisan migrate** (run seeders if any)
7. **chmod -R 777 bootstrap/ storage/** (to grant permissions to folders if required)

Make sure you followed each step